# How are contents of hidden_states tuple in BertModel in the transformers library arranged

Tags: pytorch, python-3.7, huggingface-transformers

```
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', config=BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',output_hidden_states=True))
outputs = model(input_ids) 
hidden_states = outputs[2]
```

hidden_states is a tuple of 13 `torch.FloatTensors`. Each tensor is of size: `(batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)`.
According to the documentation, the 13 tensors are the hidden states of the embedding and the 12 encoder layers.

My question:

Is `hidden_states[0]` the embedding layer while `hidden_states[12]` is the 12th encoder layer or

Is `hidden_states[0]` the embedding layer while `hidden_states[12]` is the 1st encoder layer or

Is `hidden_states[0]` the 12th encoder layer while `hidden_states[12]` is the embedding layer or

Is `hidden_states[0]` the 1st encoder layer while `hidden_states[12]` is the embedding layer

I havent found this found clearly stated anywhere else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion in understanding the output of BERTforTokenClassification class from Transformers library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60847291/confusion-in-understanding-the-output-of-bertfortokenclassification-class-from-t)

Comment: Yeah. So to be clear, final state vectors means the last encoder layer of BERT. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source-code](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_bert.html#BertModel.forward) for BertModel, it can be concluded that hidden_states[0] contains the outputs of the initial embedding layer, and the rest of the elements in tuples contain the hidden states in the increasing order of each layer. Simply put, hidden_states[1] contains the outputs of the first layer of BERT and hidden_states[12] contains the last i.e. 12th layer.